# Do we really need interface classes for the dependency inversion principle?

Tags: design-patterns, c++, interfaces, solid, dependency-inversion

As a practical example, imagine a `Gripper` class which represents a robotic gripper in a simulation.
`Gripper` has a `TryGrip` method, which checks if there's a `GrippableItem` in the correct position (within the gripper's rectangle). If there is, the gripper takes control of the item until it is dropped:

```
class GripperItemLocator  //Struggling to find a good name
{
public:

    virtual std::unique_ptr<GrippableItem>
    FindItemInRange(Rect rect) = 0; 
};

class Gripper
{
public:

    bool
    TryGrip(GripperItemLocator& itemLocator)
    {
        auto item = itemLocator.FindItemInRange(CalcCurrentRect());
        if (item)
        {
            TakeControlOfItem(std::move(item));
        }       
    }

private:

    Rect
    CalcCurrentRect() const;

    void
    TakeControlOfItem(std::unique_ptr<GrippableItem> item);
};
```

In accordance with the dependency inversion principle, we have a `GripperItemLocator` abstraction in order to decouple the gripper from the rest of the world. If the where and how `GrippableItem`'s are located in our program changes, this does not concern the gripper, only the class(es) that implement `GripperItemLocator` must change.

I'm wondering if we really need interface classes for this? Say we just have a regular class doing the same job:

```
class GripperItemLocator  
{
public:

    std::unique_ptr<GrippableItem>
    FindItemInRange(Rect rect)
    {
        //Immediate implementation
    }   
};
```

I realize this does no longer have the ability to select different implementations at run-time, but say we're 100% sure there won't ever be a need for this, we're only interested in the decoupling. Do we lose anything else that I'm overlooking, or is this just as good ?

Comment: DIP is merely a guideline which says *details should depend upon abstractions* - it has nothing to do with any particular programming language features such as `interface` or abstract classes.  Indeed, the DIP applies equally to programming languages which have no concept of an `interface`.     It's a (deliberately) language-agnostic bit of advice, since there are many different possible ways to build abstractions which have nothing whatsoever to do with classes -- DIP is about reducing coupling rather than about use of any particular patterns or language features.

Comment: When deciding to apply the DIP, it can make sense to treat data dependencies differently from behavioural dependencies. To inject different behaviour or different implementations you do need interfaces or function pointers. But to inject different data (e.g. for testing) a normal pointer or reference can be sufficient. So the question is: are you more concerned with providing the `GrippableItem` data or the `FindItemInRange()` behaviour to the `Gripper::TryGrip()` method?

Comment: @amon The concern is that the where and how `GrippableItem`s are stored could require change over time if the world around the gripper changes. A second conveyor might be installed, each conveyor now holding it's own collection of `GrippableItem`s. We want to decouple the `Gripper` from such changes, only `GripperItemLocator` would require an update to match the new situation. But we do not require run-time polymorphism, and such changes would be rare. The program would only contain a single `GripperItemLocator` implementation at a time.

Comment: Note that your noun should be a verb here. This language has free verbs (it's not Java). Instead of having a GripperItemLocator class you can have a LocateGripperItme function.

Comment: (Comment 1 of 2) DIP suggests that, based on past experience, the "interface" (i.e. the way a caller (interface consumer) tells a callee (interface implementer) to do something) tend to be more stable than the caller's code and the callee's code. Thus, the "interface" lasts longer (between necessary changes), and therefore can be made "more dependable" than either. However, for software projects that change more rapidly, one may need to be prepared to eschew the best practices, i.e. allow the software to be in a more messy state than software projects that are more stable.

Comment: (Comment 2 of 2) The nice thing about interface is that you can add more interfaces later. This is the ISP: interface segregation principle. If the current `GripperItemLocator` works fine for `GripperItem` but is inappropriate for a future `ConveyorBelt`, instead of modifying `GripperItemLocator`, you should simply add a new interface `ConveyorBeltItemLocator`. This assumes the programming language allows you to apply ISP principle cleanly. There may be some boilerplate involved, but the fact that "interfaces are stable" will ease some code maintenance pains.

Comment: (Comment 3 of 2) There's a useful adage: ["Three strikes and you refactor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)). The idea is that if you encounter the "pain" or the "repetition" the third time, you refactor. In your example, you can refactor now, or refactor later. This helps avoid premature abstractions, especially in software projects of highly chaotic change nature.

Answer (score 5):

The DIP is not an end in itself, it is a means to an end.

Let us, for example, assume you use the DIP for unit testing. If you want to be able to test `Gripper` in isolation, without the "real" `GripperItemLocator`, then you need a way to replace the latter by a mock. The canonical way of doing this is by using an interface, or in C++ an abstract virtual base class.

But if you say it is sufficient for you to create tests for `Gripper` always using a real `GripperItemLocator` object, then you can stick with that approach and don't provide an interface / virtual base class.

How to make this tradeoff depends heavily on how complex the classes are, how simple or hard it is to debug them when you cannot test them in isolation, and how much time you need to fix an error in case one occurs, but you don't know in which of the two classes the root cause is hidden.

Comment: If I want to test `Gripper` in isolation I could just provide it with a mock fixed `GrippableItemLocator` class in the test-program. Why does it need to be a interface/virtual base class if I don't require run-time polymorphism?

Comment: @Unimportant: you are right, this is not mandatory. Using an interface/virtual base class is the standard approach "by the book", which works by a run-time mechanics in different programming languages, even when "Gripper" is part of a lib designed to follow the OCP. But if one can use a compile-time mechanics to replace `GripperItemLocator` by a mock, that might be ok, too.

Comment: ... however, one has to check if this does not result in huge build times - replacing each "injectable" class by a mock using a compile time mechanics results in compiling the same class for each "mock" once again, instead of compiling the class once. In larger systems, this can become a serious issue.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Inversion' part of dependency inversion requires interfaces, or interface like constructs.

The idea is your class with a dependency no longer specifies what that dependency is. instead the calling code tells it what the dependency is.

The interface just says, whatever you pass me, I'm gona try calling it like this.

If you used a class or even an abstract class to define that you would want that class to be empty of implementation. Effectively an interface.

Answer (score 1):

The [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) aims at decoupling high level from low level classes with the help of an interface:  high level classes use the interface, and low level classes implement the interface.

The usual C++ equivalent to an interface is an abstract class that has only pure virtual member functions. However, there are other alternatives.

In fact, any polymorphic class could be used for dependency inversion, provided the high level class would only invoke virtual member functions thereof. Example:

```
class GripperItemLocator  
{
public:    
    std::unique_ptr<GrippableItem>
    virtual FindItemInRange(Rect rect)    // <-- it should be virtual
    {
        //Immediate implementation
    }   
};
```

You could later define a derived class that overrides the virtual function.  Overriding means that even the `Gripper`,  would use the overridden function if the constructor is provided with the derived class.

```
class GripperFragileItemLocator  : public GripperItemLocator
{
public:

    std::unique_ptr<GrippableItem>
    FindItemInRange(Rect rect) override 
    {
        //Immediate implementation that takes extra care of fragile items
    }   
};
```

This is still dependency inversion: you do not depend on a single implementation, but you depend on something that is abstract, that can be specialized further.

However, be very careful.  If `FindItemInRange()` would not be virtual, the `Gripper` would always invoke this function, even if you'd provide a derived `GripperItemLocator` with its own implementation.  So it would look like dependency inversion, but it's not: In reality `Gripper` would fully depend on a lower level concrete class. `itemLocater` would then just be an argument like any other (without inverting anything).

Using an interface is therefore the safest approach:  no risk of accidentally using a non virtual member, no risk of (mis-)using an abstraction that is not sufficiently abstract.  The boundaries are very clear.

**One word about templates**

When R.C.Martin wrote his seminal article about dependency inversion in May 1996, the C++ templates did not exist.

Template provide some other way to design high level elements that do not depend on the low-level:  a template just uses some lower level abstraction and makes assumptions about the interface it should provide.  A style that uses this approach extensively is [policy driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design#Policy-based_design).

However, while it achieves similar goals, it is significantly different from DIP:  templates do de facto define the interface that the lower-level class should implement.  So if the higher level depends on an abstraction, the lower level still depends on the higher level and not on an abstraction itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a baseclass instead of an interface, and pass instances of the base class or a subclass. If you use the pattern for testing, then a stub class that you try to substitute is likely not derived from the baseclass but totally independent so you lose out.

You can use a fixed instance of a fixed class, but then dependency injection becomes rather pointless. Not saying you can’t do it, but why would you?

Of course if you started with a baseclass and figure out you should have used an interface, that’s a trivial change. Unless you used knowledge about the class that you shouldn’t have.

Comment: "You can use a fixed instance of a fixed class, but then dependency injection becomes rather pointless. Not saying you can’t do it, but why would you?" To isolate the `Gripper` from the rest of the world. The `Gripper` would no longer depend on the concrete way `GrippableItem`s are stored and any changes to this would only require `GripperItemLocator` to be updated. We do not require run-time polymorphism and the program would only contain a single `GripperItemLocator` implementation at a time. What does a virtual base class buy me extra that a fixed class doesn't ?

Comment: You don’t make any sense. If the class is fixed, there is no need for dependency injection.